# Tesseract OCR or OpenCV for non-existent language

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

There is an alphabet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/txrYB.jpg) that matches each character with an English letter, I also have SVG images for each character.
I want to write a program that, based on a screenshot (like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sY2v.jpg), will "translate" the text from this screenshot to English for me. Can you tell me what I need to use to write such a program?

Comment: A possible solution: create your own "OCR engine" by implementing an image classifier. A Support-Vector Machine (SVM) could suit the task. The SVM performs well on symbol classification problems with small training datasets. Check this out: https://learnopencv.com/handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to "train" Tesseract to understand your alphabet.  It's not trivial.

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html

Answer (score 0):

This means you need to get an OCR engine that supports this language. Even if you train Tesseract, you train it to support a new font for an existing language, not a new one.